# Where cell is not equal to.. MySQL query (!=)

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

Can someone tell me how I can do a MySQL query that selects all row with an id != 1?
Please give me example of it.

Comment: Have you looked on google for 'Not equals SQL' ? It's a very basic SQL query and it's better you learn how to construct it rather than being given the answer.

Comment: Who upvoted this question? Closing as too vague. I mean, he has the answer (`!=`) in the question title. Is he having trouble placing it in the SQL? or using the mysql functions? or PDO? or what?

Comment: Why the close votes for `not a question` it is definitely an answerable question.

Comment: @Johan: But he didn't use a search engine!

Answer (score 13):

You didn't provide much detail, but it seems your own title answers the question: use `WHERE id != 1`. It works in MySQL, but the SQL standard is `<>`, not `!=`.

Comment: The only really correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

In standard ANSI SQL, not equal is represented as: `<>`

Comment: or != I always tend to use the php operators keeps it standard then.

Comment: Or by `!=` it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id <> 1
```

You also can use `!=` instead of `<>`

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id != 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<>` or `!=`, both works for MySQL